# Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended Error on Tfs 2015 build definition

Tags: .net, tfs, build, msbuild, tfs-2015

I have a solution that includes some class libraries, one wep api project and one web project. I need to publish my api project into a sub folder of web projects publish folder.

I have a build definition on tfs 2015 that builds and publishes my web project and class libraries successfully. Now i try to extend this build definition as publish api project  into web projects sub folder. I tried to do something as explained [here](http://sedodream.com/2013/09/21/HowToExtendTheWebPublishProcessWithoutModifyingProjectContents.aspx#a14e3bfc5-b31f-4994-917d-411e3c7d8240) ; and that are some settings created by me :

this is my publish.proj codes for msbuild settings :

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='' ">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
<!-- Location for build output of the project -->
<OutputRoot Condition=" '$(OutputRoot)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\BuildOutput\</OutputRoot>
<!-- Root for the publish output -->
<PublishFolder Condition=" '$(PublishFolder)'==''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\Publish</PublishFolder>
```

```
 <ItemGroup>
<ProjectsToBuild Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\MyWeb\MyWeb.csproj">
  <AdditionalProperties>
    VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
    Configuration=$(Configuration);
    OutputPath=$(OutputRoot);
    WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;
    publishUrl=$(PublishFolder);
    DeployOnBuild=true;
    DeployTarget=WebPublish;
    PublishProfile=$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)
  </AdditionalProperties>
</ProjectsToBuild>


  <ProjectsToBuild Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\MyWebApi\MyWebApi.csproj">
  <AdditionalProperties>
    VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
    Configuration=$(Configuration);
    OutputPath=$(OutputRoot);
    WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;
    publishUrl=$(PublishFolder)\api\;
    DeployOnBuild=true;
    DeployTarget=WebPublish;
    PublishProfile=$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)
  </AdditionalProperties>
</ProjectsToBuild><ItemGroup>
```

And on tfs at i setted up Msbuild Arguments as :

> "/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishSettingsFile=Source/MySolution/publish.proj
>   "

But when i executed my my build definition i got an error as :

---

> Package/Publish task
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded failed to
>   load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly
>   installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is
>   recommended.

---

I  am sure that Microsoft Web Deploys updated version is installed on my build server.

**UPDATE/EDIT**

I asked to ict  team (guys who working with servers) could they reinstall web deploy tool; and after reinstall *the current error was fixed* ; but still nothing happening. It doesn't give any error but doesn't publish anything neither web project nor api project.

Anybody have an idea about this, what is my wrong ?

Comment: What's you result if you connect to the TFS build agent with the credentials used for the build service and manually run the  build?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT i didn't try this, but i checked the build output file, it seems it builds both project successfully but couldn't publish any one.

Comment: Can you publish it successfully if you build and publish it manually from the build server?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT actually i don't have to permission to try manually at build server; because of that i executed /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishSettingsFile=Source/MySolution/publish.proj this line by command prompt, it succesfully build and publish web project, and build webapi project successfully but don't publish it; publishes web project again to api's target publish folder. Am i have a wrong in settings file ?

Comment: So there are two issues in your question, the first one is the build cannot be published from TFS server. And then second one is the web api project cannot be publish from local machine?